# Amazon RDS Mysql max_used_connections is only 3

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am setting up Amazon's EC2 & RDS to perform benchmark testing of our application. I have created EC2 (m4.xlarge) and RDS(db.m3.large) instances. Pushing load for 100 concurrent users, and while monitoring i could see max_used_connection is only 3.

```
mysql>  show variables like 'max_connections'; show global status like '%connections%';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 604   |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

+-----------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                     | Value |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
| Connection_errors_max_connections | 0     |
| Connections                       | 7     |
| Max_used_connections              | 3     |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

The time taken to process each request is close to 4000 ms which is quite high for our application.
Why the max_used_connections are only 3 when there are more no of concurrent users?

Comment: are you testing a specific query? How many tables do the benchmarked queries access?

Comment: No, i am not testing for any specific query, i am testing with a couple of scenarios, thats user authentication. I do write on a table and read from 4 to 5 tables.

Answer (score 2):

**Connections** is the number of connection attempts - successful or not.

**Max_used_connections** is the highest number of concurrent connections